# Terminal plugin for Jenkins shows error 403

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

i try to install terminal plugin on Jenkins and have a problem with it. I download latest version of plugin from

```
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Terminal+Plugin
```

and after i installed it i reboot server and then i run command in terminal(no matter any) i get an error : [JENKINS TERMINAL] ERROR: 403
Here screenshot: 
[image]
Maybe whom know issue ? how can i fix it ? Thanks for suggest.

Comment: Add a jenkins user with the home `“/var/lib/jenkins”`.
`useradd -d /var/lib/jenkins jenkins` where /var/lib/jenkins is a home directory for Jenkins of mine. Adduser as Jenkins.

Comment: thx for reply!! for mine too , i need just add a user just type in console "useradd -d /var/lib/jenkins/ " ?

Comment: Have you add Jenkins as a user in your CLI , `useradd -d /var/lib/jenkins jenkins` ??? If you had add it , then try to reboot again.

Comment: useradd: user 'jenkins' already exists  This message i receive , then type service jenkins restart and then i try to run terminal , i have a same problem :( maybe i need to swith user for mine ? but how i can do that.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, this error happens when "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" security option is enabled in Jenkins Global Security Settings.
But it is *strongly recommended* that CSRF protection be left **enabled**, including on instances operating on private, fully trusted networks.
So, may be **refuse using Terminal plugin is the best decision**, especially that his last release (1.4) was 9 years ago and depended on  now deprecated JQuery-UI plugin.